# How to configure Junit in Jenkins with Maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, junit, automation, automated-tests

I have a maven project with many Junit tests. It's actually a regression test repository. So now I want to build a Jenkins job to run the regression test automatically when building instead of downloading the repo and running all the tests in IDE every time. Any suggestion for that or any link for me to do more research? 
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are already using maven to build the project, does it already run the tests?  For example does the command "mvn test" show that tests have run?  If so you just need to setup a jenkins job to run the maven build.

There are a lot of tutorials on how to setup jenkins and jenkins jobs to perform maven builds.  You can configure a jenkins build to build when a change is pushed to git for example. You can also configure email alerts in the jenkins job to notify when a build (or test) fails.

Here is an example tutorial for maven++jenkins:
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/how-to-setup-jenkins-for-a-maven-project/

Comment: Yes, I can use mvn test to run the test